# How do i resolve the Error: Cannot find module '/node dist/api/server.js/dist/server.js

Tags: node.js, docker, ubuntu, npm

MY docker File

```
FROM node:10.16
# Create app directory
WORKDIR /node dist/api/server.js

# Install app dependencies
COPY . .


# Run the npm commands
RUN npm install -g node-pre-gyp --unsafe-perm
RUN npm install -g node-gyp --unsafe-perm
RUN npm install -g grpc --unsafe-perm
RUN npm install -g bcrypt --unsafe-perm
RUN npm install bcrypt --save --unsafe-perm  
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
# Bundle app source
COPY . .
# Start the development/staging server
EXPOSE 3000
```

Comment: better to show your server.js where you server the `dist` folder.

Comment: when do u get the error?

Comment: This is because of Node version issue. So i change node10.16 to12.13

Comment: Changed the WORKDIR /usr/src/app.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the error by Changing my Docker file

FROM node:12.13

## Create app directory

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

## Copy the files

COPY . .

## Run the npm commands

RUN npm install

## Start the development/staging server

EXPOSE 4200 
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]

Comment: Npm install and ng serve are all take care by my package.json file.